# Golang embedded struct type

Tags: go, struct, embedding, composite-literals

I have these types:

```
type Value interface{}

type NamedValue struct {
    Name  string
    Value Value
}

type ErrorValue struct {
    NamedValue
    Error error
}
```

I can use `v := NamedValue{Name: "fine", Value: 33}`, but I am *not* able to use `e := ErrorValue{Name: "alpha", Value: 123, Error: err}`

Seems that embedding syntax was ok, but using it doesn't work?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Embedded types are (unnamed) fields, referred to by the unqualified type name.

[Spec: Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is an *anonymous field*, also called an *embedded* field or an embedding of the type in the struct. An embedded type must be specified as a type name `T` or as a pointer to a non-interface type name `*T`, and `T` itself may not be a pointer type. **The unqualified type name acts as the field name.**

So try:

```
e := ErrorValue{NamedValue: NamedValue{Name: "fine", Value: 33}, Error: err}
```

Also works if you omit the field names in the composite literal:

```
e := ErrorValue{NamedValue{"fine", 33}, err}
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Nn9Myd3nb5).

Comment: Omitting the field names does work as mentioned, however if your struct has many fields then unfortunately you'll also be required to pass them. For example for a struct with four properties, if your embedded struct is one of the first fields then you'll need to initialize it like `ErrorValue{nil, NamedValue{"fine", 33}, nil, nil}` which doesn't look as clean as passing the unqualified type name of the embedded struct in. The first method as mentioned is a bit better but I can't help but feeling it's a bit unnecessarily complicated and unwieldy (compared to a language like Python at least)

Answer (score 7):

For deeply nested structs, the accepted answer's syntax is a little verbose. For example, this :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Alternative struct {
    Question
    AlternativeName string
}

type Question struct {
    Questionnaire
    QuestionName  string
}

type Questionnaire struct {
    QuestionnaireName string
}

func main() {
    a := Alternative{
        Question: Question{
            Questionnaire: Questionnaire{
                QuestionnaireName: "q",
            },
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", a)
}
```

([Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5bZDkmBl3-_d))

Could be rewritten like this:

```
a := Alternative{}
a.QuestionnaireName = "q"
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the wonderful answer by icza.

you can simply do this:

```
v := NamedValue{Name: "fine", Value: 33}
e := ErrorValue{NamedValue:v, Error: err}
```

and it works just fine. checkout the example [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/zZZ-NKo0Z4S)