# Inheritance syntax. What is the difference?

Tags: go, struct, types

In Go what is the difference below?

I tried to search, but I couldn't think of a right term to describe them. How are they officially called?

#1 - Parent inside struct:

```
type MyTime struct {
    time.Time
}
```

#2 - Parent right after my type without struct definition:

```
type MyTime time.Time
```

For #2, I can initialize my type with another time.Time like `mt := MyTime(t)`.
How to initialize #1 type with another time.Time variable?

Comment: There is no inheretence in Go, so there's no such thing as "Go inheritance syntax"

Comment: Good to know that there is no inheritance in Go. Sorry for the inappropriate title, but I will leave it for lesson.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go is not an object oriented language, there is no type hierarchy and inheritance. For details, see [What is the idiomatic way in Go to create a complex hierarchy of structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144622/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-in-go-to-create-a-complex-hierarchy-of-structs/29145086#29145086) and [Go embedded struct call child method instead parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390736/go-embedded-struct-call-child-method-instead-parent-method/29390981#29390981).

Your first example creates a new type `MyTime` [embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) `time.Time`. By embedding a type, all fields and methods of the embedded type gets *promoted* and are available as if they were fields or methods of the embedder type, very handy when you want to implement an interface for example (because the promoted methods will "exist" without having to declare them).

You can instantiate it like (for details, see [Golang embedded struct type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189605/golang-embedded-struct-type/45189658#45189658)):

```
t := MyTime{Time: time.Now()}
```

Your second example creates a **new** type, all methods will be stripped from it. This comes handy when you do not want the existing methods to be part of the new type. A shining example of this is to define the `String()` method or override marshaling behavior when you want to call the original behavior in your implementation, for details see [Call json.Unmarshal inside UnmarshalJSON function without causing stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176625/call-json-unmarshal-inside-unmarshaljson-function-without-causing-stack-overflow/43178272#43178272). You can create a value of it using a simple type conversion:

```
t := MyTime(time.Now())
```

Comment: It may be worth to add that there is no inheritance in Go. It is possible to approach some properties by using type embedding, but that's all.

Comment: @aureliar Done, was still editing the answer.